# graphlookup in mongodb - query

Tags: json, mongodb, formatting, lookup, graphlookup

I have a data set

> db.users.insertMany([
> {"_id":1, "name":"abcd" },
> {"_id":2, "name":"abcd"},
> {"_id":3, "name":"abcd" },
> {"_id":4, "name":"abcd"},
> {"_id":5, "name":"abcd" },
> {"_id":6, "name":"abcd"},
> {"_id":7, "name":"abcd" },
> {"_id":8, "name":"abcd"},
> {"_id":9, "name":"abcd"},
> {"_id":10, "name":"abcd" },
> {"_id":11, "name":"abcd"},
> {"_id":12, "name":"abcd"},
> {"_id":13, "name":"abcd"},
> {"_id":14, "name":"abcd"},
> {"_id":15, "name":"abcd"},
> {"_id":16, "name":"abcd"},
> ])
>
> db.users_hirarchy.insertMany([{
> "_id": "1101",
> "_from": 14,
> "_to": 15
> },{
> "_id": "1102",
> "_from": 14,
> "_to": 16
> },{
> "_id": "1103",
> "_from": 15,
> "_to": 3
> },{
> "_id": "1104",
> "_from": 15,
> "_to": 5
> },{
> "_id": "1105",
> "_from": 15,
> "_to": 7
> },{
> "_id": "1106",
> "_from": 3,
> "_to": 1
> },{
> "_id": "1107",
> "_from": 3,
> "_to": 2
> },{
> "_id": "1108",
> "_from": 3,
> "_to": 4
> },{
> "_id": "1109",
> "_from": 3,
> "_to": 4
> },{
> "_id": "1110",
> "_from": 3,
> "_to": 4
> },{
> "_id": "1111",
> "_from": 3,
> "_to": 4
> }
>
> ])

What I want to achieve is something like this

```
{
 nodes:[
 {
 "_id" : 3,
 "name": "abcd"
 },
 
 {
 "_id" : 4,
 "name": "abcd"
 }
 ] ,
 hirarchies : [
 {
 "_id" : 3,
 "Hierachy" : [
 {
 "_id" : "1106",
 "_from" : 3.0,
 "_to" : 1.0,
 "depth" : NumberLong(0)
 },
 {
 "_id" : "1107",
 "_from" : 3.0,
 "_to" : 2.0,
 "depth" : NumberLong(0)
 } ] },
 {
 "_id" : 4,
 "Hierachy" : [
 {
 "_id" : "1106",
 "_from" : 3.0,
 "_to" : 1.0,
 "depth" : NumberLong(0)
 } ] } ]
```

I have written a query but it doesn't give the required results. how to do it using graphlookup.
my tried query is

```
 db.users.aggregate([
 { $graphLookup: {
 from: "users_hirarchy",
 connectToField: "_from",
 startWith: "$_id",
 maxDepth: 0,
 connectFromField: "_to",
 depthField: "depth",
 as: "hirarchy"
 } } ,
 {$project:{"Data":{
 "id":"$_id",
 "name":"$name"},
  
"Hierachy":"$hirarchy"}
 }])
```

How can I achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i achieved this using facet in aggregate as

```
db.users.aggregate([
{ $graphLookup: {
from: "users_hirarchy",
connectToField: "_from",
startWith: "$_id",
maxDepth: 0,
connectFromField: "_to",
depthField: "depth",
as: "hirarchy"
}
},  {
    $facet: {
        "Node": [
        {
          $project: {
            "hirarchy": 0
          }
        }],
      "hirarchy": [
        {
          $project: {
            "hirarchy": 1,
            "_id": 1
          }
        }

]}}
])
```